# Php variables wont work after ajax get

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a problem with PHP variables. I am showing username which user id is logged in with `$_SESSION['uid'];`.

Like `$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];`

and I have to get the username with

```
$data = $Details->UserDetails($uid);
$data_username = $data['username'];
```

So in the index page shows me `<?php echo $data_username;?>` but when i use the `$data_username` in the following code it is giving me error.

```
    <?php 

    include_once ("includes/datas.php"); 
    //session_start(); and $data_username will be come within datas.php
    if ($_GET['action'] == "get_all_posts") { get_all_posts($db,$config); }
    function get_all_posts($db,$config) {
     $sql = "select * from `posts` where ((
     to_uname = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $data_username)."' AND 

     from_uname = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['client'])."' ) OR (

     to_uname = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['client'])."' AND 

     from_uname = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$data_username)."' )) order by post_id DESC ";
    }
    ?>
```

I am getting **Notice:  Undefined variable: data_username** What I am missing here anyone can tell me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: try to make an echo $data_username; under include_once, lets see if its there

Comment: And it doesn't seem like you're running the query, or returning the query string either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pass `$data_username` in to the function ie,

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "get_all_posts") { get_all_posts($db,$config, $data_username); }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your variable inside of your function you need to say to your function to use this variable. add `global $data_username`under your `function get_all_posts($db,$config) {``

So the correct code is :

```
include_once ("includes/datas.php"); 
//session_start(); and $data_username will be come within datas.php
if ($_GET['action'] == "get_all_posts") { get_all_posts($db,$config); }
function get_all_posts($db,$config) {
 global $data_username; // Try to add this line
 $sql = "select * from `posts` where ((
 to_uname = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $data_username)."' AND 

 from_uname = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['client'])."' ) OR (

 to_uname = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_GET['client'])."' AND 

 from_uname = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$data_username)."' )) order by post_id DESC ";
}
```

Comment: Usage of the global keyword isn't a good practice - it should be passed as an argument to the function instead

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u should figure out the concept of global variables and local variables.
Which means u cannot use a variable in ur function that havent defined in it yet except the variable is global.

You can send the variable by parameter like this:

`function get_all_posts($db,$config,$data_username)`

or use the keyword 'global' inside your function to claim the variable like this:

```
global $data_username;
```

But always use objects while handling complicated data.